# How do I avoid getting xssed on <%=model.data%>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, xss

Is there a way to avoid xss using `<%=Model.data%>` on an aspx page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, always encode output:

```
<%: Model.data%>
```

Note the `:` instead of the `=`

Comment: This is assuming .net4.0, right?  the `:` behavior didn't exist prior to that I believe.

Comment: So all .net projects before .net4 is in trouble!?

Comment: @user54197 - No, previously one could use Html.Encode. Html.Encode is still available, but the ":" syntax is more terse.